# How to get data in a one dimensional array for a single column?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am using MYSQLI query to extract data into an array. But when printing the array content, it looks that data is being populated into sub array. This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';

// Choose the y-axis
$sql = "SELECT `O3` FROM giordan_mod ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$resulty = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$datay = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulty, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
      $datay[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($datay);'</pre>';
?>

<?php
$test = array(4, 6, 9, 15);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($test);'</pre>';
?>
```

But when printing the array, the result are as follows:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40.25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39.64
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40.13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40.28
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 15
)
```

But I would like that MYSQLI query input data into an array and not sub array. That is I need $datay array looks as $test array.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns an array representing a row of data from your SQL command. Even if you only fetch a single command, it will always be an array. To fetch fetch a single column you need to use [`mysqli_fetch_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-column.php).

You can use [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) instead. It is easier and offers more functionality including [a method to fetch a single function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#column).

If you are stuck with mysqli, then you can use a loop and fetch the single column yourself.

```
$sql = "SELECT `O3` FROM giordan_mod ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$resulty = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$datay = [];
foreach($resulty as $row) {
    $datay[] = $row['O3'];
}
```

or even simpler:

```
$sql = "SELECT `O3` FROM giordan_mod ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$resulty = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$datay = array_column($resulty->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'O3');
```

Comment: Please consolidate duplicate content.

Comment: @mickmackusa No need. It's good as it is now.

Comment: With different pieces of advice on the same topic spread across Stack Overflow? I disagree.  How unfortunate that researchers will need to open more than one page to see all the viable techniques.  We can serve our knowledge better than this.

Comment: @mickmackusa It's a good well-written duplicate.

Comment: The question is upvoted so it will survive as a signpost.  Your advice should be evaluated and sorted on a canonical page to provide an optimal researcher experience.  Your answer cannot be sorted in solitude.